# Steps to integrate javaScript in vaadin 6

Tags: javascript, vaadin

I need to integrate javascript with vaadin 6. I googled and got nothing to be understandable.
Can anyone please suggest me a step by step process to integrate simple javascript into vaadin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Vaadin 6 you should be able to use the executeJavascript method in Window like so:

```
getWindow().executeJavaScript("alert(\"Hello JavaScript\");");
```

Comment: So if executed this how to check that the javascript is executed correctly. I dont know aything about jscript. Is there anyway to find if it is excuted correctly?

Comment: Not from the server side. You could open the jsdebugger in the webbrowser of your choice (Usually with F12) and look what it is doing. But if you don't know javascript, perhaps best learn javascript without vaadin. Mixing java/vaadin and javascript is not the simplest of things ;)